# How to ADD latest values if not 0

Tags: sql-server

Is there a better way of adding the latest 3 values in a row where the value is not 0 (i.e, skip column when value = 0)?

Example :

```
       [Jan]      [Feb]     [Mar]       [Apr]      [May] 
       [2]        [3]       [10]        [0]        [7]
       [2]        [3]       [10]        [0]        [0]
       [2]        [3]        [0]        [0]        [7]
       [2]        [3]       [10]        [0]        [7]
```

Looking for the row values; 20, 15, 12, 20.

At the moment I'm only thinking of a massive case statement...

Comment: `SUM` won't work here anyway, `SUM` works across rows, not Columns. What determines a column is the "latest" column? This sounds like a design flaw if you're adding a new column every time for a "latest" value.

Comment: Is there at least an `ID` column, or something? Do these go up to `Dec`? Raelly you should be normalising your data as well.

Comment: Latest as in; [May] + [Apr] + [Mar], however, if any of those columns are 0, move on to find the first 3 columns with positive values.

There is an unique ID per row.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by unpivoting the columns ordering them and then summing like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyRows AS M
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT SUM(ColumnValue) AS SumValue
FROM
    (
    SELECT TOP 3 V.ColumnValue
    FROM (
    VALUES
        (1,Column5)
        ,(2,Column4)
        ,(3,Column3)
        ,(4,Column2)
        ,(5,Column1)
        ) AS V(RankMe,ColumnValue)
    WHERE V.ColumnValue <> 0
    ORDER BY V.RankMe
    ) AS SumValues
    ) AS TopThree
```

[Example at dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9f2f9a79fdd68e37a1eb8ae1261a48d0)

However as others point out we're unsure why you'd want to do this, I suspect your data model has issues and you'd be better with these values in columns to start with.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming** there is an ID column, and **assuming** the columns go up to `Dec`.

You need to unpivot your data and normalise it. Then you can *easily* aggregate it. This is how you would do it "on the fly":

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT YT.ID,
           V.MonthNo,
           V.[MonthName],
           V.[Value],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YT.ID, IIF(V.[Value] = 0,0,1) ORDER BY V.MonthNo DESC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Jan',1,Jan),
                            ('Feb',2,Feb),
                            ('Mar',3,Mar),
                            ('Apr',4,Apr),
                            ('May',5,May),
                            ('Jun',6,Jun),
                            ('Jul',7,Jul),
                            ('Aug',8,Aug),
                            ('Sep',9,Sep),
                            ('Oct',10,Oct),
                            ('Nov',11,Nov),
                            ('Dec',12,[Dec]))V([MonthName], MonthNo, [Value]))
SELECT YT.ID,
       SUM(V.[Value]) AS [Aggregate]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 3
GROUP BY YT.ID;
```

Ideally, though, you should be fixing your data model.

Comment: Thanks - data model is built in excel. Thought a quick import and few sql queries would be faster at getting to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert columns to rows using `CROSS APPLY` and aggregate:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY mnum DESC) AS rn, mval
    FROM t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        (1 , Jan),
        (2 , Feb),
        (3 , Mar),
        (4 , Apr),
        (5 , May),
        (6 , Jun),
        (7 , Jul),
        (8 , Aug),
        (9 , Sep),
        (10, Oct),
        (11, Nov),
        (12, Dec)
    ) x(mnum, mval)
    WHERE mval <> 0
)
SELECT id, SUM(mval)
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [RowID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[Jan] INT
   ,[Feb] INT
   ,[Mar] INT
   ,[Apr] INT
   ,[May] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May])
VALUES (2, 3, 10, 0, 7)
      ,(2, 3, 10, 0, 0)
      ,(2, 3, 0, 0, 7)
      ,(2, 3, 10, 0, 7);

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [RowID]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [RowID] ORDER BY CASE [column]
                                                                    WHEN 'Jan' THEN 1
                                                                    WHEN 'Feb' THEN 2
                                                                    WHEN 'Mar' THEN 3
                                                                    WHEN 'Apr' THEN 4
                                                                    WHEN 'May' THEN 5
                                                               END DESC
           ) AS [MonthID]
          ,[value]
    FROM @DataSource
    UNPIVOT
    (
        [value] FOR [column] IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May])
    ) UNPVT
    WHERE [value] <> 0
)
SELECT [RowID]
      ,SUM([value])
FROM DataSource
WHERE [MonthID] <= 3
GROUP BY [RowID];
```

The idea is simple:

- unpivot the data
- order the months from latest to newest excluding months without values
- sum the values but for the last 3 months only